# $matches[0] not displaying data on screen but says it is there?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
$str = "<p><example:wow id='test' style='hello' /></p>";

preg_match_all ("/<example:wow(.*)[^>]>/", $str, $matches);
```

My $matches[0] says there is data there (string length 43) but there is not string output on the screen.

> array(1) { [0]=> string(43) " " }

If I remove the `<` from before the word example: I can see an output on $matches[0]. Why am I not really getting a string value for $matches[0] when there is a `<`? My $matches[1] is fine regardless of either scenario but I need to capture all of $matches[0].

Comment: You probably output it to somewhere where angle brackets have meaning, e.g. a web page, and browsers typically interpret it as html. Use view source then.

Comment: @user983223: as an aside question, what do you need to extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting data on screen probably because the browser is trying to render an unknown html/xml tag:

With your code I'm getting this result on $matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <example:wow id='test' style='hello' /></p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  id='test' style='hello' /></
        )

)
```

So, for debugging reason, try to:

```
print_r ($matches);
```